# Django Query: How to use sql "union" and "not in" function

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can use union and "not in" function in django query. I have searched on it but cannot find any example

```sql
SELECT id,address
    FROM tbl_nt
    WHERE st_id IN (1,2) AND name = 'foo'
    UNION (
        SELECT d.id,d.addrses
            FROM tbl_nt_123 d
            WHERE d.name='foo' AND condition_id NOT IN (
                SELECT condition_id 
                    FROM tbl_conditions
                    WHERE version_id = 5
            )
    )
```

i have tried this query for lower portion but didn't work

```py
tbl_nt_123.objects.values_list('id', 'address').exclude(
    condition_id=tbl_conditions 
).objects.filter(version_id=5).values_list(
    'condition_id', flat=True)
)
```

How can i do this?

Please refer me some good links or books for understand advance django queries.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you should just add the `__in` lookup modifier:

```
tbl_nt_123.objects.values_list('id','address').exclude(
    condition_id__in=tbl_conditions.objects.filter(version_id=5).values_list('condition_id',flat=True))
```

As for the union, you can fake it using the `|` operator.

```
union = queryset1 | queryset2
```

Comment: can you suggest me some links or books for understand queries

Comment: @AskQuestion Actually the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/) has always been more than enough for me. You can google for some extra tips (like the union thing) but I generally think that if you are going to need something really fancy and unusual, that's probably a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Django querysets now have a .union() method. Something like this:

```
tbl_nt.objects.filter(st_id__in=(1, 2), name='foo').union(
    tbl_nt.objects.filter(name='foo')
    .exclude(condition__in=Condition.objects.filter(version_id=5))
).values_list('id', 'address')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#union